# Binding to lines in flowchart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowchart

I'm using [flowchart.js](http://flowchart.js.org) to create diagrams. I want to be able to bind a click event to each arrow on the diagram to perform some action to that unique path.

As far as I can see in the inspector, these lines don't have IDs... Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I verified what you wrote and you're correct, the lines (svg paths) don't have IDs.  Also, it looks like they don't have much of a programming API.  So I came up with a hacky way of assigning IDs for each path.

After you make your call to `diagram.drawSVG(...);` add the following code create unique IDs for each path.

```
var i = 0;
$("path").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("id", "path" + i.toString());
  i++;
});
```

I then added a click handler to the path elements to verify the IDs were properly assigned.

```
$(document).on("click", "path", function () {

  //Display to the console
  var clickedPath = $(this)[0];
  console.log(clickedPath);

  // Build a string of attributes by looping them
  var alertString="";
  for (i=0; i < clickedPath.attributes.length; i++) {
    alertString += clickedPath.attributes[i].name + "=" + clickedPath.attributes[i].value + "\n";
  }

  //Alert the attributes
  alert(alertString);
});
```

You can view the results at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoqPQG?editors=0010